# IIS Redirects for both HTTPS and HTTP

Tags: redirect, iis, url-rewriting

I am trying to setup a redirect that will detect if https is used and redirect traffic to https://example.com.au and if http is used redirect traffic to http://123.com.au.

I'm currently using IIS Rewrite.

I've tried doing a few things but it isn't working.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with these rules:

```
<rule name="Redirect with HTTPS" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.*)" />
    <conditions><add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^ON$" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="https://example.com.au/{R:1}" />
</rule>
<rule name="Redirect without HTTPS" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.*)" />
    <conditions><add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="http://123.com.au/{R:1}" />
</rule>
```